# KnockoutJS - Assign Observable value to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to see if I can assign a JavaScript variable to the value of a value of a KO Observable.

The reason for this is I want to assign it to a jquery module, as a property.

I know I can do:

```
    var viewModel = {
    firstName : ko.observable("Bert"),
    lastName : ko.observable("Smith"),
    pets : ko.observableArray(["Cat", "Dog", "Fish"]),
    type : "Customer"
};
viewModel.hasALotOfPets = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.pets().length > 2
}, viewModel)


var jsonData = ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

But, what if I don't want everything that is in the view model?  Can i just only select n number of items?

Comment: Which items do you want to omit?  Are there sufficiently few that you could exclude them manually?

Comment: Not necessarily.  This was just an example that I provide.  But for example, I would want to only get like firstName and type.  I just want to know if I can only get select values.

Comment: You may be able to do something with the knockout mapping plugin, but I'm not sure of the syntax off the top of my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two concepts here:

1. Retrieving the object from a Knockout observable
2. Manipulating a JavaScript array

Code:

```
var start = 1; // index of Dog 
var n = 1; // just one item 
var jsonData = ko.toJSON(viewModel.pets().slice(start, start + n));
```

In Knockout, observables are functions. To set its value you call it with a parameter. To get its value, you call it.

JavaScript arrays have a slice function that can be used to get a smaller array.

UPDATE based on comments on the question:

If you want to take n fields from viewModel, `ko.toJSON` will work on a subsetted view model:

```
var n = 2;
var count = 0;
var subModel = {};
for (var k in viewModel) {
    if (count >= n) break;
    if (viewModel.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        subModel[k] = viewModel[k];
        count++;
    }
}

var jsonData = ko.toJSON(subModel);
```

If you want specific fields only, create a subsetted model with those:

```
var jsonData = ko.toJSON({
    firstName: viewModel.firstName,
    type: viewModel.type
});
```